# Power use on Acer Aspire (Cannot remove battery), How to save battery life?

Tags: laptop, battery, acer-aspire

I own an Acer Aspire m5-581t, In which the battery cannot be removed, I use my laptop all the time for 6-7 hours everyday.

Do I just keep the battery at 100% connected to the AC power or shall I remove the AC Power and start using the battery once It reaches 100%?

How do I save my battery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you should unplug it intermittently and allow it to discharge (though not discharge completely, at least not on a regular basis).

One of the better researched articles I found was at the [Lifehacker site](http://lifehacker.com/5875162/how-often-should-i-charge-my-gadgets-battery-to-prolong-its-lifespan). There is a follow up on the same site [here](http://lifehacker.com/5966576/prolong-laptop-battery-life-with-the-battery-care-settings-or-by-removing-the-battery-when-plugged-in). Interestingly the battery care utilities from manufacturers are actually useful, who knew.